# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I need help. I'm using pdf-lib to load pdf doc from local disk. First I loaded the pdf with the file browser button, and fetch the url from it as below.

```
const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
```

and the url is

```
"blob:http://127.0.0.1:8080/49f0cea3-8092-4a52-ad6b-f521af8ba318"
```

err msg

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Fialed to fetch
```

This code is running in a local http-server(by npx http-server). anybody knows what the problem is?

Comment: Please include text, not images of text. The image you included is near unreadable.

Comment: sorry, ive edited it

Comment: You can not load a local file using fetch, function fetch will request your server to load a file from server side. You need File API, please to see [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: On react app, however, I can load a local file using fetch. What's different?

Answer (score 3):

I solve it. The problem is that 'revokeObjectURL()' was called before I use the url.

Comment: Your self-answer is fine, though please edit the question so that it includes anything required for anyone to answer it, that is, you must include the code where revokeObjectURL is called since as is, there is no way from the question only to know you did revoke it.